# Write The Shortest Program To Check If A Binary Tree Is Balanced

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, binary-tree, tree-traversal

For each node in a balanced binary tree, the maximum difference in the heights of the left child subtree and the right child subtree are at most 1.

The height of a binary tree is the distance from the root node to the node child that is farthest from the root.

Below is an example:

```
           2 <-- root: Height 1
          / \
         7   5 <-- Height 2
        / \   \
       2   6   9 <-- Height 3
          / \  /
         5  11 4 <-- Height 4
```

Height of binary tree: 4

The following are binary trees and a report on whether or not they are balanced:

[image: Test Case 1]

The tree above is **unbalanced**.

[image: Test Case 2]

The above tree is **balanced**.

Write the shortest program possible that accepts as input the root of a binary tree and returns a falsey value if the tree is unbalanced and a truthy value if the tree is balanced.

**Input**

The root of a binary tree. This may be in the form of a reference to the root object or even a list that is a valid representation of a binary tree.

**Output**

**Returns truthy value:** If the tree is balanced

**Returns falsey value:** If the tree is **un**balanced.

**Definition of a Binary Tree**

A tree is an object that contains a value and either two other trees or pointers to them.

The structure of the binary tree looks something like the following:

```
typedef struct T
{
   struct T *l;
   struct T *r;
   int v;
}T;
```

If using a list representation for a binary tree, it may look something like the following:

```
[root_value, left_node, right_node]
```

Comment: May input be empty tree?

Comment: In your initial example of a tree, if you remove the leaf `4`, is the remaining tree balanced?

Comment: No, not that example, I meant the initial one, using ASCII art.

Comment: According to my own implementation "C, 117 bytes": No, since the height of the right subarm tree starting from "5" is 2 and the height of the left subarm tree is 0.

Comment: Edits are at least 6 chars but please remove the comma from between 'balanced' and 'binary' - 'binary tree' is a noun phrase, so writing 'balanced, binary tree' is the equivalent of 'red, snow mobile' - the comma is not required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ḊµŒḊ€IỊ;ß€Ạ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjq5DW49OAlKPmtZ4PtzdZX14PpD1cNeC/4fbgYz//6O5ok0MdBSiTYA4FoiNQQxDMGEMFYoFEYamcB6CNIEJmoIYJhYgwhxZl4klQhdIC1e0oSGQZ4ZkIaq5FlCeoQGSRhAfZJAhqtkg9xkb4rZOhysWAA)

The empty tree is represented by `[]`.

Comment: Thanks Erik for being amongst the first to answer this question. Jelly certainly is a very popular language on this site. I think I should take the liberty to implement this language. Good to learn from a robust golf-scripting language.

Comment: Congrats Erik the Outgolfer, you are winner.

Answer (score 3):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 49 bytes

```
N+_/B/C:-X+B,Y+C,abs(X-Y)<2,N is max(X,Y)+1.
0+e.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BTsMwEETP8VdYPa1lO46JA20AIbX3HhCHRAhFBrmoUpqg2FU4@deDnRYKHEaaWc2@3Y@hb/t3bsf9NG1pI9ZiU/KKrllNN0y/Wqh4Te6u2BbvLT7oT6hYTahMUUZNOjljXfOmrYGnwRiCS44SQEnS0JhZcI/GHluH77Ebjub292CnW2tQQkJr1w8H7WDhxxL7Dvsx9Z3vFux5ppw2XkiK0APHl5MqE6CEEZArATIqD8mQYIrZkFmgYoKiCG4ZdHMuqdWlFNh/0FIKuD7Tv1mwjElmpxivrIJ@aHn4Q/5DB@70BQ)

Represents trees as `Value/Left_Child/Right_Child`, with the empty tree being the atom `e`. Defines `+/2`, which outputs through success or failure, with an unbound variable (or one already equal to the tree's height) on the left and the tree on the right--if the height argument is unacceptable, add 9 bytes to define `-T:-_+T.`.

```
N + _/B/C :-            % If the second argument is a tree of the form _Value/B/C,
    X+B,                % X is the height of its left child which is balanced,
    Y+C,                % Y is the height of its right child which is balanced,
    abs(X-Y) < 2,       % the absolute difference between X and Y is strictly less than 2,
    N is max(X,Y)+1.    % and N is the height of the full tree.
0 + e.                  % If, on the other hand, the second argument is e, the first is 0.
```

Comment: (If the value of each node could be omitted from the input, `_/` could be taken out for -2 bytes.)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 49 bytes

```javascript
h=([l,r])=>l?(d=h(l)-h(r))*d<2?1+h(d>0?l:r):NaN:1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5RDoIwDIbfPUmnwzAZoihwAy6w7IEwwjQLM8N4/VmYosaHv/27tf16bR7N2LrL7R4NVnXe6wKEoU6SojQVqEKDIZEGR8hanXcV22hQZVyZ3JG8buqc@dYOozXd1tgeNAghJBUhSsqSqQg2RfHZJpj46@PdybOlkx9Rh9mmOMQnxZKQ0@oPJZah9Gtl4MWS4pL9zAgv2ccn7BeHdzLMjE0c/wQ)

-9 bytes by Arnauld.

---

## JavaScript, 58 bytes

```javascript
h=([l,r])=>l?(l=h(l),r=h(r),m=l>r?l:r,m+m-l-r<2?m+1:NaN):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7REoIgEEXf@xIYsZHELAv9A3@A4cExJ2sWabDp922FspoeLvcu7O7h2jyasXWX2z0e7Kmbpl4SBcxpKkuoCMieAGUOzVFmJJSugsIxE5kYYnfcVCbiRd3UtOBTa4fRQrcGeyY9UUpppsKpGU/nIsQMJXxM0cTr4d0p8qVT7FE7HzMcErMSTelh9YdSy1D2tTLwEs1wydYzwk3@ySn/xeE/OTrnnjM9AQ)

Use `[]` for null, and `[left, right, value]` for nodes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 50 bytes

```
f@_[x_,y_]:=f@x&&f@y&&-2<Depth@x-Depth@y<2;f@_=1>0
```

Use `Null` for null, `value[left, right]` for nodes. For example, the following tree is written as `2[7[2[Null, Null], 6[5[Null, Null], 11[Null, Null]]], 5[Null, 9[4[Null, Null], Null]]]`.

```
    2
   / \
  7   5
 / \   \
2   6   9
   / \  /
  5  11 4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7RCoJAEHz3KxaEezrJ9c7UUrmHnqP35RAJRUEjwkCJvv0yMkth2WF2Zme3zbuqaPOuPufGlCqjPuNDpndJqXrGSjUw5njxobh2leqdDw6xtx@tCaauOd3qS0c2OCmUZGsNDDbKgod0SdLx3jQchCQcS0z03TUH9P@5/qEFAPIr@j7JkGTAQUazR/PRg0jb@cQ6K5w4ugthSseIMFh@IwUJXI2i5a5@mhc)

Comment: That's really pretty!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>133</s> 125 bytes

```python
b=lambda t:((max(l[0],r[0])+1,abs(l[0]-r[0])<2)if(l:=b(t[1]))[1]and(r:=b(t[2]))[1]else(0,0))if t else(0,1)
h=lambda t:b(t)[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tU/LToQwFN3zFU3YtLFj6MAoEvkA/YWmMcUp0ligaYuRr8dLGXRM3Lq4r3PPPT21c@jGIS@tW3RvRxeQ9AGl6HmC0o4O9fJdD29IIqMBGSeIFoVOIR/cutCDnUJiaji7NTooJ82L@pAGxwUmZGlqI/vmLFGoMO7lJzY8E9RBIjeMysZH4BCBxyPRLTZV3eDAmSAEkhzO2G3IcUOU8QpnNCNARgFdRkaS7ucpoK/UxYLLgDtsCEnSp9WTj/9S0s/odbTzwYJ1VSUpLzLKC8oF5TkUtkYeRwHBTpd2T8UGnKAUJcT9N7V4@EUVIM0Y5Xe7@pVSGVuW7cg6wDW7EgMLOftDW4jlf2S/AA)

Takes a tree in the "list" format: A node is `[value, left, right]` with `left` and `right` being nodes.

Invoke the function `h`.

Returns `0` or `False` for an unbalanced tree.
Returns `1` or `True` for a balanced tree.

### Ungolfed:

```python
# Returns tuple (current height, subtrees are balanced (or not))
def balanced(tree):
  if tree: # [] evaluates to False
    left = balanced(tree[1])
    right = balanced(tree[2])
    # If  the subtrees are not both balanced, nothing to do, just pass it up
    if left[1] and right[1]:
      height = max(left[0], right[0]) + 1
      subtrees_balanced = abs(left[0] - right[0]) < 2
    else:
      height = 0 # Value doesn't matter, will be ignored
      subtrees_balanced = False
  else:
    height = 0
    subtrees_balanced = True
  return (height, subtrees_balanced)

def h(tree):
  return balanced(tree)[1]
```

-10: Reversed logic to get rid of `not`s

If taking arguments in the middle of a call is allowed, this could be shortened to (115 bytes)

```python
(b:=lambda t:((max(l[0],r[0])+1,abs(l[0]-r[0])<2)if(l:=b(t[1]))[1]and(r:=b(t[2]))[1]else(0,0))if t else(0,1))(_)[1]
```

with `_` being the tree to check.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 162 bytes

```javascript
f=x=>{for(f=0,s=[[x,1]];s[0];){if(!((d=(t=s.pop())[0]).a&&d.b||f))f=t[1];if(f&&t[1]-f>1)return 0;if(d.a)s.push([d.a,t[1]+1]);if(d.b)s.push([d.b,t[1]+1])}return 1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzBCoMwEER/pb2EXarBnGX9kZBD0rjUHlSSWAT129NIS@ltmPdmnvZl4z0Mc6rHyfc5M63UbTwFYGqqSFqvlTKmjboxLW4DwxXAEySKcp5mQCwApRXCS7fvjMiUtDJtMVmIM9bcKQx9WsJ4ac7eS4tlvcQH6JKrU7opgx/m/pj7seN7oI6c3w)

The format of the input is an object

```javascript
root={a:{node},b:{node},c:value}
```

### Explanation

```javascript
for(f=0,s=[[x,1]];s[0];){if(!((d=(t=s.pop())[0]).a&&d.b||f))f=t[1]
```

Performing breadth first search find the depth of the first node which is missing one or more branches.

```javascript
if(f&&t[1]-f>1)return 0;if(d.a)s.push([d.a,t[1]+1]);if(d.b)s.push([d.b,t[1]+1])}
```

Continuing the breadth first search, return zero if any element is two deeper than the depth of the first node missing branches.

```javascript
return 1}
```

If no such node is found, return 1

Comment: There is probably some way to do the breadth first search better but I couldn't think of it.

Comment: I think this fails for some valid cases such as the very first example which should become balanced when you remove the leaf `4`.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 56 bytes

```
f(t)=t!=()&&(-(f.(t.c)...)^2<2 ? maximum(f,t.c)+1 : NaN)
```

With the following struct representing the binary tree:

```
struct Tree
    c::NTuple{2,Union{Tree,Tuple{}}}
    v::Int
end
```

`c` is a tuple representing the left and right nodes and the empty tuple `()` is used to signal the absence of a node.

Falsey value is `NaN`, any integer is truthy.

Comment: Assuming the encoding is UTF-8, this is actually 57 bytes because of the `≢`, according to [TIO's built-in byte counter](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P02jRNO25FHnIg1NNTUNXY00PY0SvWRNPT09zTgjGyMFe4XcxIrM3NJcjTQdkIS2oYKVgl@in@b//wA). Anyhow, welcome to CG&CC!

Comment: Yes, you're right. I corrected it, so that it's now actually 56 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 67 bytes

```
fun N.c():Int=maxOf(l?.c()?:0,r?.c()?:0)+1
fun N.b()=l?.c()==r?.c()
```

Where

```
data class N(val l: N? = null, val r: N? = null, val v: Int = 0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY0xDsIwDEXn5hQeY1GhskaEipElDJzAFLWqcFOaphUIcfaSEMGCvXw/f/tfe8@tXS7kCSqmcQQjZ2JgBaYEDXZiziES90dmBQfrAypwqScLZl1JVAHpju7HWnIZQamK3H0VrjYiWc8SdTJondafHx21VpJrRgV75@ixPXnX2maHT5HFzCHEGZkaMf/pNKcS2S3ceLZyiDEoXssb)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>99</s> <s>96</s> 94 bytes

```python
lambda A:A==[]or(abs(D(A[1])-D(A[2]))<2)*f(A[1])*f(A[2])
D=lambda A:A>[]and-~max(map(D,A[1:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7BDoIwDL37FRw3MxIKQ5E4ExL@ou4wQogmMghy0Iu/PgsIYuLh9bUv7Xttn/2lsaGr1NndTF2UxsvSTCnUTcdMcWc5yxA09wcONefHkG@rSRuZtE2uvqcn1MaW/qs2D1abluWCdlM6dG13tb1XMZSBQClQC4yIYEA0jpoA8aedi5yEmEgmhP2yKg8/q/TIEgEgcDenrByTsYVgVoaBXGBlSq9E8CeD/N0b)

3 bytes from [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king).

Takes input as: empty node is `[]`, and other nodes are `[<value>, <leftNode>, <rightNode>]`. Outputs `0/1` for False/True.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 117 bytes

```
h(T*r){r=r?1+h(h(r->l)>h(r->r)?r->l:r->r):0;}b(T*r){return r->l&&!b(r->l)||r->r&&!b(r->r)?0:abs(h(r->l)-h(r->r))<=1;}
```

Struct implementation is the following:

```
 typedef struct T
    {
        struct T * l;
    
        struct T * r;
    
        int v;
    
    } T;
```

[Try This on JDoodle](http://jdoodle.com/a/1rdN)

Comment: This appears to be 117 bytes, though you can do `<2` for that last check instead

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how valid this is, since it relies on a data structure defined outside of the submission